# Finding Power Using Recursion

Tags: python, recursion

In Python 3

```
def power(base,exponent):
    if exponent == 1:
        return base
    return base * power(base, exponent - 1)
```

I haven't considered corner cases ( exponent <= 0)

Why don't we use the above-written code in-place of code computed using [Divide and Conquer Technique](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-calculate-powxn/), this code looks more simple and easy to understand? Is this code less efficient by any means?

Comment: The other version makes less recursive calls, but this one is simpler to understand. I personally find it unnecessary to optimise a recursive power implementation as it can also be written in an iterative fashion.

Comment: Both of them are recursions, call stack will decide the optimize algorithms. Above algorithm is interactive recursion and have o(n) complexity meantime the other one has o(log(n)) time complexity. So People will prefer 2nd one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the steps taken for calculating 2^8 with your code:

```
power(2,8)=
2*power(2,7)=
2*2*power(2,6)=
2*2*2*power(2,5)=
2*2*2*2*power(2,4)=
2*2*2*2*2*power(2,3)=
2*2*2*2*2*2*power(2,2)=
2*2*2*2*2*2*2*power(2,1)=
```

These are the steps taken for calculating 2^8 with divide and conquer:

```
power(2,8)=
power(2,4)**2=
power(2,2)**2**2=
power(2,1)**2**2**2=
```

As you can see your method takes O(n) steps while divide and conquer takes O(lg(n)) steps which is significantly faster.

Using recursion for such problems is never a good idea if you are concerned with speed since as you can see iterative approach(tail recursion in functional languages) is usually much faster, in this example it's twice as fast as you can see in the benchmarks, as for the divide and conquer approach, you should always use that unless you are working with powers of less than ~22.

**Here are some benchmarks:**

The codes:

```
def r_power(base, exponent):  # recursive credits to OP
    if exponent == 1:
        return base
    return base * r_power(base, exponent - 1)


def lindc_power(x, y):  # linear divide and conquer, credits to Smitha Dinesh Semwal
    if y == 0:
        return 1
    elif int(y % 2) == 0:
        return lindc_power(x, int(y / 2)) * lindc_power(x, int(y / 2))
    else:
        return x * lindc_power(x, int(y / 2)) * lindc_power(x, int(y / 2))


def lgdc_power(x, y):  # logarithmic divide and conquer
    if y == 0:
        return 1
    elif int(y % 2) == 0:
        return lgdc_power(x, int(y / 2)) ** 2
    else:
        return x * lgdc_power(x, int(y / 2)) ** 2


def i_power(base, exponent):  # iterative, credits to Yugandhar Chaudhari
    acc = 1
    while True:
        if exponent == 0:
            return acc
        base, exponent, acc = base, exponent - 1, acc * base
```

The results:

```
|---------------------------------------------------------------------|
| base | power   | recursive | iterative | linear dc | logarithmic dc |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 2    | 10      | 1.27 µs   | 746 ns    | 8.99 µs   | 2.33 µs        |
| 2    | 22      | 2.96 µs   | 1.58 µs   | 18.6 µs   | 2.95 µs        |
| 2    | 100     | 15.1 µs   | 8.31 µs   | 75.3 µs   | 4.14 µs        |
| 2    | 500     | 96.7 µs   | 48.9 µs   | 312 µs    | 5.69 µs        |
| 2    | 1000    | 424 µs    | 178 µs    | 1.3 ms    | 6.58 µs        |
| 2    | 1500    | 201 µs    | 108 µs    | 620 µs    | 7.89 µs        |
| 2    | 2000    | 435 µs    | 242 µs    | 1.23 ms   | 8.15 µs        |
| 2    | 3000    | error     | 409 µs    | 2.49 ms   | 10.3 µs        |
| 2    | 6000    | error     | 1.13 ms   | 5.01 ms   | 17.6 µs        |
| 2    | 10000   | error     | 2.64 ms   | 9.84 ms   | 25.2 µs        |
| 2    | 20000   | error     | 8.74 ms   | 19.9 ms   | 45.7 µs        |
| 2    | 100000  | error     | 161 ms    | 82.4 ms   | 249 µs         |
| 2    | 200000  | error     | 626 ms    | 159 ms    | 532 µs         |
| 2    | 1000000 | error     | 15 s      | 651 ms    | 3.23 ms        |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

My maximum recursion depth is 3000.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem yes, I just realized that I had not renamed the inner calls:)) I didn't see your comments because I was redoing the benchmarks.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem I'm gonna increase my recursion depth now to do some more tests.

Comment: This implementation of `dc_power` is linear (this is notated explicitly in the webpage linked from the question) because it does two recursive calls instead of one. There is no wonder that it is not faster.

Comment: @GZ0 doesn't python cache the results?

Comment: Most languages that I know of would not do that unless being explicitly told to, because there is no way to know whether a function call can have any side effect. In Python you need `@functools.lru_cache` for that.

Comment: @Gz0 I can't believe I was so dumb to just copy paste the code without any thinking. I'm gonna do benchmarks again... sorry...

Comment: Had you read the webpage carefully you would see the implementation is a naive version that was notated to have an O(n) time complexity. An improved version is also provided.

Comment: @GZ0, I didn't mean to blame the link, I meant, I can't believe I was so dumb to just copy paste without thinking/reading :P

Comment: *you should always use that unless you are working with powers of less than ~22* Be careful that 22 number is specfic to the implementation so do not take it as a general conclusion for the algorithms. A better implementation of `lgdc_power` can make it faster and only loses on very small exponents.

Comment: @Gz0 how can you make it better staying with python?

Comment: [An improved version](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSEnPSU5viC/PLUoPjO3oCi/LDVFIymxOFVHIbWiQNOKSwEIMtNAHAVVBSMIHwRKFGzx61XQ11cw0oSrL0otKS3KUwBJK2gBdQMxWC41B2I6xSYjG1mcaoUubfi/oCgzr0QDm8nGOgqGBpqa/wE)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this could be less efficient if it is not tail recursive. Recursion creates stack frames for a too large number you can go out of memory. Right way would be expressing it using tail recursion. You just need to use a variable to store the result `acc` here it will evaluate the result in a variable instead of making recursive function calls

```
def power2(base,exponent,acc):
    if exponent == 0:
        return acc
    return power2(base,exponent-1,acc*base)

print(power2(10,2,1)) #start acc from 1 initially
```

But python is not tail optimized so this is the way to use tail optimization here

```
def power2(base,exponent,acc):
    while True:
        if exponent == 0:
            return acc
        base,exponent,acc = base,exponent-1,acc*base

print(power2(10,100,1))
```

Comment: python is not tail optimized and this gives maximum recursion error

Comment: @yukashimahuksay yes try the second implementation it wont